# Css is not used by jsx in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I use ReactJS with Webpack and TypeScript.
I'm trying to include CSS with React. But my CSS is not use by my React application.
I created a global.d.ts file to declare my css module. I imported my css into my.tsx file but when I add a class to an element, nothing works.

I have already tried to install a css module but I didn't succeed. So, I just made the solution to create a global.d.ts file

global.d.ts :

`declare module '*.css';`

Hello.tsx

```
import * as css from './Hello.css';

export interface HelloProps {
  compiler: string;
  framework: string;
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps, {}> {

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <p className={css.test}> Test </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Hello.css

```
.test {
   color: red;
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
   rules: [

     .....

     { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] }
   ]
 },
```

The word "test" is written in black.
When it should be in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be due to you not having modules set to true in your css-loader options.

```
// webpack.config.js

rules: [
  {
    test: /.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

Also, i would just do the following as there's no need for the `*` import.

`import css from './Hello.css'`

and then in your jsx:

`<Component className={css.test} />`

Comment: What is the best solution?
Paul's solution works. But is that a correct way to do it?

Comment: @Karti If you would like to use css modules with webpack and not let your css classes leak out to other components, my approach is the way to go. Otherwise simply importing the css file directly will expose the css classes to the entire application and you can use `.test` anywhere. In that case it would be better importing the stylesheet at the app initialisation level.

Comment: Ho yes. It's cleaner indeed. But with your solution, i have this error in my Chrome Log : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined. I added the following : ```<p className={css.test}> Test </p>```

Comment: With :  import * as css from './Hello.css';      it's work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

im quite new to react but i think if you remove:
"import * as css from './Hello.css';" And Replace it with "import './Hello.css';"

Comment: He is trying to use css modules without using the option in his webpack config.

Comment: Thank you Paul, this solution works !
I think webpack makes things very complicated.